# traverse a specific path of a website with authentication. Web crawler or standard HttpClient?

Tags: java, http, web-crawler, web-scraping

I have to traverse a website in a specific path and extract information from there. Below are the high level actions. Appreciate if someone can let me know if I need a web crawler or I am better off coding this flow using HttpClient or JDK's built-in functionality.

1. Go to a website
2. Login using a form (transitions to http (s))
3. Click on a particular link (transitions back to http)
4. Fill in the form data and click on Search button
5. website returns the results 1 page at a time
6. Click on each search result
7. Extract data from that link
8. perform steps 6 and 7 until all search results are read.

Comment: This could be done with a crawler. I am not as experienced with Java as I am perl, but it looks like some of it could be done with HttpClient

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but if anyone is looking for an existing web crawler that does that, know that [Norconex HTTP Collector](http://www.norconex.com/product/collector-http/) is a web crawler supporting form-based authentication.  You can specify your start URL(s) in addition to your login form URL.  It will log you in and crawl your site/URLs as you would expect.  It will either follow all links or only those matching your criteria (regex pattern, max URLs, max depth, etc).  It can integrates with different search engines (Solr, Elasticsearch, Autonomy IDOL, etc) or you can define yourself what to do with the crawled documents.